# bash shell .inputrc behaving strangely

Tags: bash

I recently had to switch to bash shell from tcsh. In order to use the tcsh's  ESC+p and `set complete=enhance` on bash shell, I have added following three commands in `.inputrc` file of my bash shell:

```
bind 'set completion-ignore-case on'

bind  '""\ep": history-search-backward'

bind  '"\en": history-search-forward'
```

After that I sourced the .inputrc and I was getting the expected behavior those commands are meant for. But I noticed a strange problem that if I type 'b' on my command prompt, it is getting converted to `\en": history-search-forward'`.

Then I commented out the last two commands in the .inputrc and sourced that again. Then again the same problem recurred and this time 'b' was converting to 'set completion-ignore-case on'. And if I comment out all the three commands in .inputrc and source that then 'b' is getting typed properly.

The only thing I understand from this is that whatever the last bind command is attached to, 'b' is just switching to that.

Please help me, I am clueless of how to get rid of this problem.

Also note, that if I remove 'bind' and simply write the commands as below then it says bash shell command not found when I source it:

```
set completion-ignore-case on

""\ep": history-search-backward

"\en": history-search-forward
```

thanks.

simon

Answer (score 2):

The `.inputrc` file is not a shell script. You do not run it through your shell (that means you don't use `.` or `source` on it).

I believe that, in an inputrc file (like the default `.inputrc`) your latter (`bind`-less) versions are the correct ones and that you should simply allow bash/readline to load that file for you automatically at shell init (or use <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>C-r</kbd> to tell readline to re-read the inputrc file live).

That being said, barring the doubled leading quotation mark I believe those original lines should have worked correctly when sourced/run through bash (though not in the `.inputrc` file).

Comment: ok, thanks for your answer. I will change .inputrc to inputrc only and remove the preceding bind pragma from the commands. Will try and get back to you.

Comment: No, `.inputrc` is the correct filename for that. I was just lazy and didn't bother with the quoting/period. My point was that you do not ask bash to read the file. You let bash let readline read it. Edited answer to hopefully be a bit more clear on that point.

Comment: thanks for further clarification. so what I understand is i will keep the .inputrc as .inputrc only (won't remove the . preceding the inputrc) and remove the preceding 'bind' from the commands in .inputrc. also I will not source the .inputrc after making the changes. but what I noticed is source-ing only enabling the expected  behavior i am looking for. please let me know how will i let bash readline to read it. I am not an expert on this , pls help.

Comment: @simon bash readline will read the `.inputrc` file at shell startup as I said in my answer. If you want it to load changes immediately you can use the default binding I also listed in my answer.